Mouse not appearing on external monitors after several minutes - ubuntu 24 kernel
I lately experience a suboptimal behavior whereby the mouse, after a few minutes of normal behavior, stops appearing on external monitors a few minutes after booting the system (Ubuntu 24.04 kernel 6.8.8 , with an nvidia RTX 3080Ti driver 550.78). It seems that the mouse may be travelling into the area of the external monitors but I don't think it can click on anything (tho this is a bit tough to determine without being able to see it). dmesg shows
[   18.433280] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Idling display engine timed out: 0x0000c67e:6:0:1173

which is possibly related.  I am using two monitors; xrandr shows
DP-4 connected 2560x1440+5120+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 400mm
HDMI-5 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1600+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 210mm

Any help appreciated.
